# How to select same value in multiple forms in Cypress

Tags: testing, select, automated-tests, cypress

Is there some way how to select same value in multiple forms (dropdowns)?

value I want to select -> apple
every form is starting with -> dropdown_form_

I was thinking about something like:

```
cy.get('[id^="dropdown_form_"]').select("apple")
```

but this doesn't work, because you can only call select on single element.

Comment: Can you add the html of your dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you just want to apply `.each()` command?

```js
cy.get('[id^="dropdown_form_"]')
  .each($el => {
    cy.wrap($el).select("apple")
  })
```

Comment: I have another question, is it possible to wait until I have specific response. Like I need to wait until data is imported from another website after I click on button for that import.

Comment: Generally you would use `cy.intercept()` to wait for the response from the other website - the question would be, what is the URL and is it different for each form?